# Processing output command with new lines redirected as Herestring

Tags: bash, newline, herestring

I'm dealing with a while loop processing a **Herestring** input:

```
one_is_achieved=0
while IFS="=" read key value ; do
  process_entry key value && one_is_achieved=1
done <<<$(output_entries)
# Dealing with one_is_achieved
[...]
```

the function `output_entries()` outputs key-values lines:

```
k1=some stuff
k2=other stuff
k3=remaining stuff
```

Problem, the **command subtitution** `$()` captures stdout but **replace ends of line by spaces**, causing `k1` entry to be `some stuff k2=other stuff k3= remaining stuff`.

Is there a way to **prevent** the replacement or to **restore** the ends of lines?

---

**Note:** I solved my problem this way:

```
while IFS="=" read key value ; do
  process_entry key value && one_is_achieved=1
done < <(output_entries)
```

But I think the original question is still relevant (preserving or restoring end of lines).

Comment: I don't see a _HERE_-string in your post.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164508/why-do-newline-characters-get-lost-when-using-command-substitution

Comment: @user1934428: `<<<`. Maybe I use the wrong term to name it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. I mixed up "here documents" and "here strings". Of course you are right that thsi is a here string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *how* command substitution is implemented in `bash` shell. The `$(..)` in unquoted form removes any embedded newlines because of the default word-splitting done by the shell. The default IFS value is `$' \t\n'` and unquoted expansion causes the splitting to happen based on any of these 3 characters.

You need to quote the substitution to prevent the word-splitting from happening. From the [GNU bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) or reset the IFS value by setting `IFS=""` before the substitution is expanded.

> `$(command)`
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing `command` in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed **`during word splitting`**.

Comment: This behaviour depends on the Bash version: 4.3 and older split an unquoted here-string, 4.4 and newer don't. The documentation always said that there is no word splitting. See [CHANGES](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES), for changes between 4.4-alpha and 4.4-beta ("Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, ..."). Compare running `cat <<< $(echo $'abc\ndef')` under Bash 4.3 and 4.4.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer with the useful information. I've anyway made it Community Wiki